# How to update existing office addin?

Tags: outlook, office365, ms-office, outlook-web-addins

We have an outlook add-in already published on the store and we now want to change the url it is pointing to (inside the manifest file). We want to know the process of doing it, will it be possible to retain the same ManifestId? Also after changing the URL, how would it reflect on the calendars where it is already installed, do the user's need to install again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update an add-in already published to Microsoft AppSource to point to a new Source location, you will need to edit your manifest to point to the new location and reupload your manifest in your SellerDashboard listing. (Don't forget to increment the version number!) Once you have uploaded your new manifest, you should submit your update to validation and the team will review the update. If approved the updated version of your add-in will automatically be psuhed to existing users.

Please do not change your manifestID as this will cause your add-in to fail validation.